# Windows phone 7: Generate pivotitems at runtime with unique names

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, pivot

I want to know if it is possible to loop through the existing pivot items and check their headers before assigning a new pivot item header and if so what would be the best was to go about it?

Comment: You're question is unclear. you should put more details on your question.

Comment: Is it possible to loop through the existing pivot items and check their headers content against a string?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

XAML

```
 <controls:Pivot Margin="12,35,12,24" Name="pivotMainList">
            </controls:Pivot>
```

Code behind

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= Count; i++)
                {

                    PivotItem myNewPivotItem = new PivotItem();
                    myNewPivotItem.Name = "piv_" + i;
                    Grid myNewGrid = new Grid();

                    myNewGrid.Children.Add(any content if you have);

                    myNewPivotItem.Content = myNewGrid;

                    pivotMainList.Items.Add(myNewPivotItem);

                }
```